# In-line Chrome extension downloads are not added to the webstore count

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am developer of Visual Inspector Chrome extension with option to install it from [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-inspector-by-canva/efaejpgmekdkcngpbghnpcmbpbngoclc?hl=en) or, from [official CanvasFlip website](https://www.canvasflip.com/visual-inspector/).

Problem is that it is not adding in-inline installation count from CanvasFlip website, resulting in stagnant webstore download count for extension.

It was working well when we had only option to install it from Chrome Webstore.

From last 3 months after we added in-line installation, there are over 14,000 installs with only a few hundred uninstalls (as per GA event installs on successful install/uninstall.) but total number of downloads in Chrome Webstore is almost same at 30,000 and worst, changing randomly (+/- 100 or so).

**As per our calculations, it is missing download counts happening via inline installation. Is it a known issue?**

It's creating confusion among team and difficult to evaluate marketing efforts. I have been trying multiple channels but there's no clear confirmation.

Will really appreciate any help in this.

Cheers, 
Vipul @CanvasFlip

Comment: As suggested in this [forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-apps/inline$20install%7Csort:date/chromium-apps/uCDbiUZ8KsM/DOG4hiQNhBYJ), you can post this in [crbug.com](http://crbug.com/). There were bug reports: [1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=298904) and [2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=298914) but were tagged as obsolete.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot, I have been posting this on all forums but no response so far.

By any chance, would you know if there's one actively being monitored for Chrome Webstore developers/extensions? 

Thanks for your help.